# Can I do programming on Linux puppy?

Tags: puppy-linux

I have a 16 year old computer on which i which to do programming and learning c++.But it so old that i think that i should install Linux puppy on it.thus can do programming on Linux puppy? or should I use Lubuntu or Debian LXDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppy, Lubuntu, Debian, or any other lightweight distro [such as those listed here](https://www.linux.com/news/best-lightweight-linux-distros-2017) will work fine.

I'd suggest that you don't install a graphical environment and go for a minimum install - i.e. work on text-only console - to avoid wasting resources. While a IDE is nice when doing software development, you can learn a programming language without it. All you need is `gcc` and a couple of other packages.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the distribution offers gcc with C++ support, you can choose any option you want. But don't expect to compile Qt on it, for example, or not in a reasonable time anyway.